# Android: Default Bitmap density when saving and loading from Internal Storage

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I'm saving a bitmap to the internal storage through the compress() method.

The bitmap was first decoded from a byte array (from camera) so I'm assuming the bitmap factory would scale it depending on the screens density.

When I later decode the bitmap from a filestream; will it be scaled again with android assuming it as being for a medium density screen?

Comment: you probably want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494889/android-images-density-and-screen-pixels

Comment: also, are absolute pixel coordinates scaled even when placing an bitmap and specifying its width?

Comment: depends also on how you define layout in the DP format then it's pixel independent.  but the view.getWidth() may return more pixels on higher density screens. read also Additional Density Considerations in the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations. so reading the documentation it will be scaled if you define it as DP. which you usually want.

Comment: Yeah, Ive read over it a few times now, says it scales any absolute pixel coordinates. But is it referring to just layouts? Including the x,y of Canvas.drawBitmap()

Comment: it won't scale unless you explicitly set it to be scaled. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925915/android-scaling-canvas-bitmap (fixed comment)